# How to create a list of functions from a list of parameters?

Tags: r

I want to create several functions using parameters and the function names contained inside a dataframe.

The for loop did not return what I was expecting, i.e each fuction to contain the parameters of intercept and slope from their line in the dataframe

```r
data <- data.frame(name = c("A","B","C"), intercepts = c(1,0.5,4), slopes = c(0.1, -2,4))

> data
  names intercepts slopes
1     A        1.0    0.1
2     B        0.5   -2.0
3     C        4.0    4.0

for(i in data$name){
  assign(i, function(x){force(i);
    data[data$name==i,]$intercepts + data[data$name==i,]$slopes*x}
    )
}
```

I know the problem has something to do with the scope, but I could not fix it using "force" as recommended by some users.

```r
> A(1)
[1] 8
> B(1)
[1] 8
> C(1)
[1] 8
```

Comment: Not. clear, why you need to create multiple objects.  Isn't this just `with(data, intercepts. + slopes)`

Comment: I would like to create different functions because i'm not applying them together necessarily. And the input is going to change too, sometimes i will want A(1) and B(10) for example.

Answer (score 0):

I messed around with it a little bit and I do not think you can get what you want because of R's weird scope rules. Maybe try a function factory instead?

```
data <- data.frame(name = c("A","B","C"), intercepts = c(1,0.5,4), slopes = c(0.1, -2,4))

factory <- function(data, i) {
  function(x) {
    data[i,]$intercepts + data[i,]$slopes*x
  }
}

factory(data, 1)(1) #> 1.1
A <- factory(data, 1)
A(1) #> 1.1
```

Or you could write code that just takes in `data`, `i`, and `x` and calculates the value outright. To be honest, what you're asking for seems weirdly unidiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it with `substitute`:

```
for(i in data$name){
  local({
    fn <- function(x) 1
    body(fn) <- substitute(data[data$name==X,]$intercepts + data[data$name==X,]$slopes*x, list(X=i))
    assign(i, fn, .GlobalEnv)
  }
  )
}
```

This does not rely on lexical scoping (which kkeey called "weird scoping rules"); `"A"` becomes hard-coded within `A()` etc:

```
print(A)
# function (x) 
# data[data$name == "A", ]$intercepts + data[data$name == "A", 
#    ]$slopes * x
```

Using `local` above is not really necessary but I did it to avoid polluting the global namespace with unnecessary objects (`fn` in this case).

A simpler version without `local`:

```
for(i in data$name){
    fn <- function(x) 1
    body(fn) <- substitute(data[data$name==X,]$intercepts + data[data$name==X,]$slopes*x, list(X=i))
    assign(i, fn)
}
```

Finally, a version for creating functions that become independent of your data:

```
for(i in data$name){
  fn <- function(x) 1
  int <- data[data$name==i,]$intercepts
  slp <- data[data$name==i,]$slopes
  body(fn) <- substitute(a + b*x, list(a=int, b=slp))
  assign(i, fn)
}

> A
function (x) 
1 + 0.1 * x
> B
function (x) 
0.5 + -2 * x
> C
function (x) 
4 + 4 * x
```